# open child form in new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a sponsor which can have many warranty management urls. I have implemented the sponsor form but having trouble to create urls child form. Problem is I need to create child in new page and show the list back to the main form. How do I do it?

My form:

```
   <%= form_for @sponsor, url: polymorphic_path([:a, @sponsor]) do |form| %>
       <%= form.file_field :logo %>
       <%= link_to "Add Warranty Service URL", new_a_sponsor_warranty_management_url_path(@sponsor), class: 'button green right' %>
   <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :sponsors do
      resources :warranty_management_urls, only: [:new,:edit,:create,:update,:destroy]
end
```

Controller:

```
def new
    @sponsor = Sponsor.new
end
```

Currently this error pops up:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"a/warranty_management_urls", :sponsor_id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:sponsor_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your route helper is incorrect. The documentation for resource route helpers may be helpful for your situation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Have you tried running `rake routes` to get the list of available routes and route helpers? I imagine you need something more like:

```
<%= link_to "Add Warranty Service URL",
            new_warranty_management_url_path,
            class: 'button green right' %>
```

You can pass a `sponsor_id` param as an argument to the path helper, but that won't work unless the sponsor has been saved, which isn't true for a new record.